# partial class template specialisation for std::vector of fundamental types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I would like to partially specialise a class template for std::vector containing fundamental types.

My approach looks like this, but [does not compile](http://ideone.com/RkJ6zC)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, bool bar = false>
struct foo {
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo<typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, std::vector<T>>::type, false> {
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "std::vector<fundamental type>" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo<std::vector<T>, false> {
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "std::vector<T>" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int>::show();
    foo<std::vector<int>>::show();
    foo<std::vector<std::string>>::show();
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct foo
{
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Alloc>
struct foo<std::vector<T, Alloc>
         , typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type>
{
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "std::vector<T>" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Alloc>
struct foo<std::vector<T, Alloc>
         , typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type>
{
    static void show()
    {
        std::cout << "std::vector<fundamental type>" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9518c68a798aa7b5)